# Optional types cannot be assigned to one of them (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, types

```
const x = (): string | number  => {
    return 'hola';
}

const n = (x: string): string => {
  return x;
}

n(x())
```

When writing this code I am receiving a compiling error within the n(x()) that says that type string | number cannot be assigned to type string. Any idea why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since `x` can return either a `string` or a `number` it's not safe to pass the result to `n` which expects a `string`. Consider the following code:

```
const x = (): string | number  => {
    return  Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'hola' : 0;
}

const n = (x: string): string => {
  return x.toLowerCase();
}

n(x())
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgB4ILwIBQEoBcD4BOAllAOYIA+CUArgLYBGApgQmgHwIDeobbBTODQJQ2AWQCGcABYA6AhKgATCHWwJOABlkBWBAH4EAcmkQANhKMI8mgNygAvqFCRYiUegxI8hEqVz4cMRkHNy8CAJCIsiycBAAMhAA7iwAwhIwTNj2IE4goFBe2FhAA)

This will fail 50% of the time, when `x` return a `number`.

You can either make `x` return just `string`, or you can check the result type before calling `n`:

```
let xr = x();
n(typeof xr === "string" ? xr: xr.toString())
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgB4ILwIBQEoBcD4BOAllAOYIA+CUArgLYBGApgQmgHwIDeobbBTODQJQ2AWQCGcABYA6AhKgATCHWwJOABlkBWBAH4EAcmkQANhKMI8mgNygAvqFCRYiUegxI8hEqVz4cMRkHNy8CAJCIsiycBAAMhAA7iwAwhIwTNj2IE4goGaCyKzoSNmgUBhwAJ4ADkwQAGbFaKjoAES+ZO0GxXhIBLEQAMpBfthYQA)